# Linq results to dataTable with copyToDataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset

I would like to have my Linq results in a dataset/datatable. The problem I have at the moment is the query variable doens't have the propperty copyToDataTable. I get this error.

> The type 'x.v_Checklist' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method
>   'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable

This is my code

```
protected void btnExcelCheckListDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet dsTest = new DataSet();
    var db = new BillingEntities();
    var query = (from u in db.v_Checklist select u).AsQueryable();
    DataTable dt =  query.CopyToDataTable();
    dsTest.Tables.Add(dt);
    ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("MyExcelFile.xls", dsTest);
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [**How to: Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx)

> *The [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable.aspx) method takes the results of a query and copies the data into a DataTable, which can then be used for data binding.
>   The CopyToDataTable methods, however, only operate on an IEnumerable
>   source **where the generic parameter T is of type DataRow**. Although this
>   is useful, it does not allow tables to be created from a sequence of
>   scalar types, from queries that project anonymous types, or from
>   queries that perform table joins.*

It's why you can't use directly the CopyToDataTable without writing some extensions.

The linked topic describes how to implement two custom `CopyToDataTable<T>` extension methods that accept a generic parameter `T` of a type other than `DataRow`.